# Linked list node equality

Tags: singly-linked-list

I'm having trouble in understanding equal sign between two nodes in a linked list.

If there are two linked list nodes n1 and n2

N1 = N2  means  value of N2  is assigned  to N1 node or N1 and N2 points to same location ?

Comment: Do you have some specific code you are talking about? Please include it in the question. In which programming language is it written?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your structure defined as

```
struct my_struct{
    int val;
    struct my_struct *next;
};
```

If N1 and N2 are structure pointer:

```
struct my_struct *N1, *N2;
```

then N1 = N2 means, N1 points to same location as N2.(The location N1 points to goes off. If it points to a dynamic memory save it to free further)

If N1 and N2 are structure variables:

```
struct my_struct N1, N2;
```

then N1 = N2 gives you a compilation error.